# set (no) Referrer-Policy tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, policy, referrer, referrer-policy

I am trying to disable sending referrer information to other website's on a tomcat 9.x webserver. I searched the tomcat documentation but there was nothing to find about this specific referrer-policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting special (security) response headers is web application task.
You can either create a servlet Filter that adds headers whichever you want:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = ((HttpServletResponse) response);
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or if you are using `Spring Security`, you can use [their header configuration feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-referrer):

Example XML configuration from `Spring Security` docs:

> ```
> <http>
>     <!-- ... -->
>
>     <headers>
>         <referrer-policy policy="same-origin" />
>     </headers>
> </http>
> ```

Example Java configuration from `Spring Security` docs:

> ```
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig extends
> WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>   @Override
>   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>       http
>       // ...
>       .headers()
>           .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN);
>   }
> }
> ```